# Transition between ViewPager and Fragment (outside ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, transition

I would like to achieve a transition between a ViewPager (filled with several instances of a Fragment called Timer2Fragment) and a RelativeLayout (which is a fragment-container and is filled with one instance of a MainMenuFragment, called mainMenu). The ViewPager itself is a child of this RelativeLayout. See my Activity_main.xml below.

What I already tried:
Get the currently shown ViewPager's fragment via the return statement within the getItem method of the FragmentStateChangeAdapter. Use FragmentManager to hide/show the currently shown ViewPager-fragment and mainMenu. No Success: I don't see any transition.

I also thought about another approach: Using LayoutTransitions since both, the ViewPager and the RelativeLayout is a ViewGroup. But it seems, that LayoutTransitions only work for transitions within the ViewGroup.

Please note, that I want to keep all used Fragments running. Thats why I worked with hide/show rather than remove/add. And thats why I also adapted the adapter a bit (Background: Each fragment shows a timer, that works in a separate thread.)

Do you have any solution for my problem?

My Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <com.chitinsoftware.kitchentimer.customViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Timer2Fragment> mPageReferenceMap = new ArrayList<>();

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Timer2Fragment myFragment = new Timer2Fragment();
        return myFragment;

        //return new Timer2Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
    }

    public Timer2Fragment getFragment(int key) {
        return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
    }

}
```

How I tried to achieve the transition:

```
    Timer2Fragment currentFragment = getCurrentTimer2Fragment();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.show(mainMenu);
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My slide_in_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

And the slide_out_right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```